# Algorithm for finding the Maximal using Divide and conquer method

Tags: algorithm

Maxima finding problem: In the 2-dimension space, we shall say that a point A=(a1,a2) dominates a point B=(b1,b2) if and only if a1>b1 and a2>b2. Apoint is called a maximal if no other point dominates it. Design an algorithm to find all of the maximal points among the given n points. 
**(Use divide and conquer method to get O(nlogn) complexity )**
For example, the circled points in the attached image are maximal points[image: Qn]

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: The best algorithm for this is just to sort the list of points in (-x,y) order, then run though the list and output any point that isn't dominated by the previous output point...  but that's not going to be what your prof is looking for

Answer (score 2):

If I have what is supposedly a list of maximal points sorted in order of X co-ordinate, with Y breaking ties, I can travel down it in the direction of decreasing X and Y should increase at each stage. If not, I can delete points where Y is not large enough to regain a list of maximal points. This costs time linear in the number of points.

This means that if I have an n log n recursive sorting algorithm I can have each recursive call mark the maximal points among those that it is returning, or return the maximal points as an additional part of the return value, and produce a merged and corrected list of maximal points, in order, for its caller. So you just need to take your favourite sorting algorithm and modify it a little to solve the problem.